# Convert \u0000\u0000 to readable in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data file that contains unicode values of \u0000\u0000, \u0000\u0018 and \u0000\u001aq{ in one column. How do I convert this to human readable format using snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake will automatically decode Unicode escape sequences. Of course, `\u0000` is the Unicode escape sequence for a null string, so it's not printable. `\u0018` is the Unicode escape sequence for "Cancel", so it's also not printable.

Here's an example with a printable Unicode escape sequence:

```
create or replace temp table t1 as select
'This \u028D is a Latin small letter turned w.' as THE_STRING;

select THE_STRING from T1;
```

If the values have already somehow landed in the fields still escaped, you can use a Javascript UDF to convert them:

```
create or replace function decode_unicode("s" string)
returns string
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
    return decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(`"${s}"`));
$$;

select decode_unicode('This is a Unicode escape code, double escaped to simulate landing in a field that way: \\u028D');
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I pass my input to the function. Unexpected token in decode_unicode. I ran this select decode_unicode('\u0000\u0000') or select decode_unicode('\u001aq{')
I already have the data in snowflake and I am trying to separate out the fields and put them into different columns

Comment: Remember that Snowflake is already escaping the backslash. To test the UDF with literal values, you need to double backslash the escape sequence. In other words, in Snowflake `\\u0000` gets sent to the UDF as `\u0000`. To test the UDF with literal values you'd have to use `select decode_unicode('\\u0000\\u0000');`. Remember though, that's non-printable Unicode.

Comment: Data was ingested into Snowflake via Parquet files as a variant column. So the field that I am trying to parse into a separate column is part of the blob as key value pair. So the data is in a table with variant column as -
{
c1 : value
c2: "\u0000\u0000"
}

Now I need to pick c2 and put it in a column after decoding the unicode values.